# Can't use external functions on c glade code

Tags: c, glade

I'm trying to create a simple program that uses glade as user interface. But I'm having a problem: if I call an external function inside the method of Button_click, as I compile the code the glade window won't open. If I don't add it, the glade window opens and functions correctly...Any help? I'm a begginer on glade...

This is where I call the outside function:

```
    G_MODULE_EXPORT void on_Button_click(GtkButton *button,gpointer *data) 
{
    /* Pull the widgets out of the tree */
    display= glade_xml_get_widget(xml, "displayLabel");
    display1 = glade_xml_get_widget(xml,"displayLabel1");
    textValue = glade_xml_get_widget(xml, "textEntry"); //vai buscar a caixa de entrada

    /* Get the string value form the Entry widgets */
    d_string = gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(textValue));

    texto = (char *)d_string;

    enviarFrase(texto);

}
```

Comment: Is `texto` a global variable???? why??? and also, what does `enviarFrase()` do, can you post it?

Comment: Yes, texto is a global variable, a char*. enviarFrase() is a function that sends characters trough serial port. That function functions correctly. Maybe my problem is from compiling, when I'm not using the external function i use: gcc -Wall -g main.c -o main -rdynamic `pkg-config gtk+-2.0 --cflags --libs` -I/usr/include/libglade-2.0/ -lglade-2.0. When I'm using the external function i use: gcc -Wall -g c1.h c1.c link.h link.c app.h app.c main.c -o main -rdynamic `pkg-config gtk+-2.0 --cflags --libs` -I/usr/include/libglade-2.0/ -lglade-2.0

Comment: If `texto` is a global variable as well as apparently all other variables used in this function, this function `no tiene sentido` rewrite your program.

Comment: I was just doing accordingly to a tutorial I found, and added that external function

Comment: Well that's a very bad tutorial, can you please provide a link to it?

Comment: It's here: http://vingladegui.blogspot.pt/2012/01/text-entry-using-glade.html
Even though here only gchar *d_string is declared, but I needed to cast to a char*

Comment: There is a site I recall called zetcode or something, search for it on google, the tutorial in the link s*cks.

Comment: Thank you very much, but zetcode doesn't have a tutorial for glade, unfortunatly

Comment: Try learning `gtk` without glade first, and then try `glade`. If your are coming from stuff like Visual Basic, and you try to find it's equivalent I am very glad to tell you there is nothing as bad as Visual Basic anywhere, so try to learn `gtk` it's not hard, trust me.